# How to get list of TDs in TR row with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, iterator

I have a simple table that looks like:

```
<tr>
<td>cell1</td>
<td>cell2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>cell3</td>
<td>cell4</td>
</tr>
```

I'm using beautiful soup to try and map the contents of the TDs to object values.

I'm doing the following:

```
rows = soup.findAll('tr')
   for td in rows[1]:
      print(td.text)
```

This prints:

```
cell1
cell2
cell3
cell4
```

I want to get the specific index of each cell.  For example:

```
print(td[0])
```

I get the error:

```
KeyError: 0
```

**How can I get the index of each TD?**

Answer (score 0):

Well of course, when you access `td` it's already one `td` not multiple `td`s, if you want to access the first `td`, do it this way:

```
rows[1][0]
```

the above code means access **ANY** first element of the second row. If you want to get only `td`s inside the row, do it this way:

```
rows = soup.findAll('tr')
for row in rows:
    tds = row.findAll('td')
    print(tds[0])
```

above code will print every first td on every row

Answer (score 0):

Another solution.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc
html = '''
<tr>
<td>cell1</td>
<td>cell2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>cell3</td>
<td>cell4</td>
</tr>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
trs = doc.trs.tds.text

print (trs[0][0])
```

Result:

```
cell1
```